# SQL: How to join two tables to get names instead Id's to search engine using LIKE?

Tags: sql, join, sql-like

I have two tables named: t_servicio and cat_clientes and are composed as follows:

**t_servicio:**
[image: t_servicio]

**cat_clientes:**
[image: cat_clientes]

Table t_servicio hosts the "Id_Cliente". So I'm doing is a search engine in many columns for now I just want to search the **"Id_cliente"** column. the question is, how I can get the names of customers (clientes) joining the table **t_servicio** with the table **cat_clientes** using the LIKE condition to find matches?

I hope can help me please!

**Edit:**

And for example, when getting the results, the columns **Marca, Producto y SubProducto** only shows the ID but I want her names and, what would be the sentence?

I want result like this:
[image: result like this]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My spanish is no good, but if I understand correctly you want to use a `LIKE` condition on the P_Nombre (that's name, correct?) in the cat_clientes table, where the cliente Id is in the t_servicio table.  If this is correct, using a simple `INNER JOIN` should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_servicio T
    INNER JOIN cat_clientes C ON C.Id = T.Id_Cliente
WHERE C.P_Nombre LIKE '%queso%'
```

**EDIT:** In response to "And for example, when getting the results, the columns Marca, Producto y SubProducto only shows the ID but I want her names and, what would be the sentence?"...

if Marca, Producto and SubProducto are also Id's then just as with Id_Cliente you will need to join to whatever table those keys reference.  For example, if there is a Products table, you would add:

```
SELECT C.P_Nombre, P.Nombre -- (Or whatever column has the product name)
FROM t_servicio T
    INNER JOIN cat_clientes C ON C.Id = T.Id_Cliente
    INNER JOIN Products P ON P.Id = C.Producto
WHERE C.P_Nombre LIKE '%queso%'
```

Same for SubProducto and Marca.

Comment: Thanks, INNER JOIN is better :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope I'm not missing something in your question, but the SQL to do this is straightforward:

```
select s.Id_Servicio, c.Nombre
from cat_clientes c, t_servicio s
where c.Id = s.Id_Cliente
and c.Nombre like '%Uno%';
```

You can extend this (add more columns to the output) to include other columns from either table. Assuming you have other tables to link together, you can build up the query. You mention tables Marca, Producto, etc, but don't provide structure, so I am guessing:

```
select s.Id_Servicio, m.Marca, p.Producto, c.Nombre
from cat_clientes c, t_servicio s, t_producto p, t_subproducto sp, t_marca m
where c.Id = s.Id_Cliente
and m.Id = s.Id_Marca
and p.Id = s.Id_Producto
and sp.Id = s.Id_SubProducto
and c.Nombre like '%Uno%';
```

Comment: And for example, when get results the columns Marca, Producto y SubProducto display yours ID but i want names, what would be the sentence?

Comment: You need to provide names of tables and the foreign keys linking them to get a correct answer, but the approach is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `cat_clientes` AS c LEFT JOIN `t_servicio` AS t ON(c.id = t.Id_Cliente)
```

Comment: This joins the tables but doesn't fully answer the question as the OP wants to know how to use LIKE to search for matches.